# SQL to Query text in access with an apostrophe in it

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to query a name (Daniel O'Neal) in column names `tblStudents` in an Access database, however Access reports a syntax error with the statement:

```
Select * from tblStudents where name like 'Daniel O'Neal'
```

due to the apostrophe in the name.

How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You escape **`'`** by doubling it, so:

```
Select * from tblStudents where name like 'Daniel O''Neal'
```

Note that if you're accepting "Daniel O'Neal" from user input, the broken quotation is a serious security issue. You should always sanitize the string or use parametrized queries.

Comment: Out of curiosity Alex why would the escaping of quotes cause a security issue ?

Comment: @RichardSpencer in certain scenarios if you pass around string variables containing unescaped `'` characters and then use them to construct SQL statements your open to *SQL Injection attacks*; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 6):

When you include a string literal in a query, you can enclose the string in either single or double quotes; Access' database engine will accept either.  So double quotes will avoid the problem with a string which contains a single quote.

```
SELECT * FROM tblStudents WHERE [name] Like "Daniel O'Neal";
```

If you want to keep the single quotes around your string, you can double up the single quote within it, as mentioned in other answers.

```
SELECT * FROM tblStudents WHERE [name] Like 'Daniel O''Neal';
```

Notice the square brackets surrounding *name*.  I used the brackets to lessen the chance of confusing the database engine because *name* is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).

It's not clear why you're using the *Like* comparison in your query.  Based on what you've shown, this should work instead.

```
SELECT * FROM tblStudents WHERE [name] = "Daniel O'Neal";
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the apostrophe in `O'Neal` by writing `O''Neal` (two apostrophes).

Answer (score 1):

...better is declare the name as varible ,and ask before if thereis a apostrophe in the string:

e.g.:

DIM YourName  string

YourName =    "Daniel O'Neal"

```
  If InStr(YourName, "'") Then
      SELECT * FROM tblStudents WHERE [name]  Like """ Your Name """ ;
   else
      SELECT * FROM tblStudents WHERE [name] Like '" Your Name "' ;       
  endif
```

Comment: And if my name is `Daniel"O'Neal`, then what?

Answer (score 1):

How about more simply: Select * from tblStudents where [name] = replace(YourName,"'","''")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for how to find all records where there was an apostrophe in the column value. Using the double ' suggested by @Alex K, I came up with

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ([column] LIKE '%''%')
```

Adding it to this question for others who maybe looking for the same resolution.

Comment: That is good for Access' ANSI-92 mode, but if you're running the query in [ANSI-89](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-wildcard-character-reference-af00c501-7972-40ee-8889-e18abaad12d1#bmansi89) mode, you need `*` instead of `%` as the wildcard.