# Building dynamic query for Sql Server 2008 when table name contains " ' "

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I need to fetch Table's TOP_PK, IDENT_CURRENT, IDENT_INCR, IDENT_SEED for which i am building dynamic query as below:

```
sGetSchemaCommand = String.Format("SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 [{0}] FROM [{1}]) AS TOP_PK, IDENT_CURRENT('[{1}]') AS CURRENT_IDENT, IDENT_INCR('[{1}]') AS IDENT_ICREMENT, IDENT_SEED('[{1}]') AS IDENT_SEED", pPrimaryKey, pTableName)
```

Here pPrimaryKey is name of Table's primary key column and pTableName is name of Table.

Now, i am facing problem when Table_Name contains " ' " character.(For Ex. KIN'1)

When i am using above logic and building query it would be as below:

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 [ID] FROM [KIL'1]) AS TOP_PK, IDENT_CURRENT('[KIL'1]') AS CURRENT_IDENT, IDENT_INCR('[KIL'1]') AS IDENT_ICREMENT, IDENT_SEED('[KIL'1]') AS IDENT_SEED
```

Here, by executing above query i am getting error as below:

> Incorrect syntax near '1'.
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ') AS IDENT_SEED'.

So, can anyone please show me the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Try doubling the single quotes that you want to keep.  For example, `KIL'1` becomes `KIL''1`, and `IDENT_CURRENT('[KIL'1]')` becomes `IDENT_CURRENT('[KIL''1]')`

Comment: Seems similar to the SO question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764197/sql-to-query-text-in-access-with-an-apostrophe-in-it/6764578#6764578

Comment: @Doug_Ivison If there are multiple ' like KIN''1 or KIN'''1 should i need to insert one more ' ?

Comment: Every ' needs to replaced by ''.

Comment: For `KIN''1`, it's still doubling:  `KIN''''1`.  I think my example code below, (which assumes you're coding for .NET), would handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape a single quote by doubling it:  `KIL'1` becomes `KIL''1`.

If a string already has adjacent single quotes, two becomes four, or four becomes eight... it can get a little hard to read, but it works :)

Using string methods from .NET, your statement could be:

```
sGetSchemaCommand = String.Format("SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 [{0}] FROM [{1}]) AS TOP_PK, IDENT_CURRENT('[{2}]') AS CURRENT_IDENT, IDENT_INCR('[{2}]') AS IDENT_ICREMENT, IDENT_SEED('[{2}]') AS IDENT_SEED", pPrimaryKey, pTableName, pTableName.Replace("'","''"))
```

**EDIT:**
Note that the string replace is now *only* on a new, third substitution string.  (I've taken out the string replace for `pPrimaryKey`, and for the first occurrence of `pTableName`.)  So now, single quotes are only doubled, when they will be within other single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace every single quote into two single quotes http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10827/understanding-single-quotes.aspx