# How to pass the string containing apostrophe to query in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android application. Actually in my app I am getting the data from sqlite database which I stored previously. But one of my db column contains strings with Apostrophes. When I pass the query it is showing error when the string with apostrophe is passed.

Below is my code:

```
String fest = "Guru Rabindranath's Birthday";

querythefest(fest);

    public void querythefest(String festname) {
        DBAdapter dbAdapter = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(this);
        try {
            dbAdapter.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("unable to create database", e.getMessage());
        }
        dbAdapter.openDataBase();


        query2 = "Select desc from List where name='"+ festname + "'";

        System.out.println("que " + query2);

        arr1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        arr1 = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDBList(query2, null);



        dbAdapter.close();
    }
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: You should use this: String[] festss =new String [] {"New Year","Guru Rabindranath's Birthday"};

Comment: Part of your problem is that you aren't using a Prepared Statement (you're potentially open to SQL Injection); using one would remove the problem, as the apostrophe would be escaped automatically, essentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest and quickest way is to escape each single apostrophe with an extra apostrope, like this:

```
String fest = "Guru Rabindranath''s Birthday";
```

Or you can use rawQuery method's selectionArgs parameter (Sql Injection)

```
query = "Select desc from List where name = ?";
mDb.rawQuery(query, new String[] { fest });
```

Comment: hi thank you for the response...if I keep single apostrophe with an extra apostrophe then do I need to insert the same in database? or in database the string with single apostrophe is enough?

Comment: That extra apostrophe is just an escape character.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape ' by following, so:

```
"Select desc from List where name ='"+ Daniel O''Neal+ "'"
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764197/sql-to-query-text-in-access-with-an-apostrophe-in-it) link

Comment: what if there are two single quotes in the string?